# Is there a way to add a NavigationNode in Quick Launch under a given node not as a child using Sharepoint Rest API only?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to add a Navigation node in Quick Launch below a given node (not as a child) using SharePoint Rest API

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function ($) {  

                $("#createQuickLaunch").click(function () { createQuickLaunch() });  

            });  
            //Create a Quicklaunch Navigation  
            function createQuickLaunch() {  
                var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/navigation/QuickLaunch";  
                var headers = {  
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                    "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
                }  
                var call = jQuery.ajax({  
                    url: endPointUrl,  
                    type: "POST",  
                    data: JSON.stringify({  
                        "__metadata": { type: "SP.NavigationNode" },  
                        'IsExternal': true,  
                        'Title': "Bing",  
                        'Url': "http://www.bing.com"  
                    }),  
                    headers: headers  
                });  
                call.done(successHandler);  
                call.fail(failureHandler);  
            }  
            function successHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
                SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Navigation created Successully", false);  
            }  
            function failureHandler(errorMessage) {  
                alert("Request Failed: unable to Navigation: " + JSON.stringify(errorMessage));  
            }  
        </script>  

        <input type="button" title="createQuickLaunch" value="createQuickLaunch" id="createQuickLaunch"/>
```

[image]

Reference:

[Add Quick Launch Link To SharePoint 2013 Site Using REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-quick-launch-link-in-sharepoint-2013-site-using-rest-api/)